# Insert values with thousands seperator into table

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following SQL to create a table with values:

```
CREATE TABLE Logistics (
    country TEXT,
    Costs_Inbound CHAR(255),
    Costs_Storage CHAR(255),
    Costs_Outbound DECIMAL(65,3)

);


INSERT INTO Logistics 
(country, Costs_Inbound, Costs_Storage, Costs_Outbound)
VALUES 
("DE", "5000", "300", "600500.815"),
("NL", "3000", "650", "250452.454"), 
("FR", "4000", "120", "750060.932");
```

and the following SQL to query values from the table:

```
SELECT country, sum(Costs_Inbound), sum(Costs_Storage), sum(Costs_Outbound),
       (sum(Costs_Inbound) + sum(Costs_Storage) + sum(Costs_Outbound)) as Total
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP;
```

You can also find the code in the `sqlfiddle` [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92d35b2/1). 
All this works fine so far.

---

Now, I want that the values go into the table with a **thousands seperator** so instead of `6000500,815`, `250452.454` and `750060.932` they should appear as `600,500.815`, `250,452.454` and `750,060.932`.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Don't do this. Thousands separator is a _presentation_ thing. At that point, it is not a number, it is a string. When you take a value out of the table, format it for display any way you want to (whether by using MySQL [`FORMAT` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) or in your client language), but let it be a number while in the database.

Comment: Especially when, as here, you're wanting to *process* this data. Keep it *as* data, not how someone wants to see it in a particular application/report

Comment: Thanks guys for the info. I am new to SQL so this helps a lot. I was just wondering because in my orignal database when I do an SQL query the results always include a thousand seperator. Maybe that is a standard setting of the MySQL workbench?

Comment: Yes, it's likely a *UI* decision made by the authors of the *client tool* you're using to access the database. (They *have* to convert everything to a string to show it to you, and they've made their own decisions about how to *perform* that conversion)

Comment: Look, while the `DECIMAL` value is in MySQL, `1234567890.1234` is stored somewhat like `10000001 00001101 11111011 00111000 11010010 00000100 11010010` ([source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4491eaf786696c5423560747eebc75b4132d082f/strings/decimal.cc#L1225)). Not like `1234567890.1234`, and especially not like `1,234,567,890.1234`. All of the latter ones are choices by code that _displays_ the number to you (usually, if the coders are nice, by taking into account which culture you belong to, as different cultures write numbers differently).

Comment: @Michi ... as mentioned in above comments, the presentation of the results is based on the Editor or UI format. Also, you need to correct your Logistics  table and change the datatype of Costs_Inbound and Costs_Storage columns to NUMBER or DECIMAL.

Comment: @ihm017. Thanks ofr the additional help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `format` function

```
SELECT country, FORMAT (sum(Costs_Inbound),2) Costs_Inbound, 
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Storage),2) Costs_Storage,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2) Costs_Outbound,
      FORMAT( (sum(Costs_Inbound) + sum(Costs_Storage) + sum(Costs_Outbound)),2) as Total
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92d35b2/7

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. So if I define the decimal places it automatically also defines the thousand seperators.